# Java localized filenames

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8, character-encoding, download

How can i set localized filenames in java.Currently everytime i click on a localized file having a non-ascii filename in my application, the windows save dialog box pops out, but it isnt displaying the filename properly if the charset is anything above ISO-88859-1.

This is my code which is saving the file.

```
            InputStream inputStream = null;
 try {
  response.resetBuffer();
  response.setContentType(fileStream.getContentType());
  response.setContentLength((int) fileStream.getContentLength());
  response.addHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
  ServletOutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int read = 0;
  int total = 0;
  inputStream = fileStream.getInputStream();
  while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
   stream.write(buffer, 0, read);
   total += read;
  }
  response.flushBuffer();
 } finally {
  if (inputStream != null) {
   inputStream.close();
  }
 }
```

I would be very helpful if someone could share their ideas on how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What gustafc says is correct, but it doesn't get you where you want to be.  [RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231) allows you to use an alternative format for non-ASCII `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` parameters, but not all browsers support it.  The way that's most likely to work, unfortunately, is to ignore what RFC 2183 says and use [RFC 2047 encoded-words](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) in the response:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; " +
    "filename=\"" + MimeUtility.encodeWord(fileName, "utf-8", "Q") + "\"");
```

Note that this may not work for all browsers.  Some variants of IE require that you URL-encode the value instead:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "utf-8"));
```

Comment: DKarp, This code was really helpful. Now i could get the desired results on all the browsers other than IE. With IE while downloading the file it is encoding the filename to display in proper format but its appending the entire URL to it and when i try to download a .xls file, it displays a download progress box with an alert on it that says "Internet Explorer was unable to open this site.The site is either Unavailable or cannot be found." I would once again like you to point me in the right direction. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What's the code you're using to set the `Content-Disposition` header for IE?  I think some versions of IE may not deal well with header folding, so make sure not to put an extra newline in the header...

Comment: I used URLEncoder for IE exactly as you specified in the answer.     response.addHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "utf-8"));

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar problems with filenames containing greek characters.I used the code provided in the answer above (my thanks to dkarp) combined with detecting which browser is used. this is the result:

```
String user_agent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
boolean isInternetExplorer = (user_agent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1);
if (isInternetExplorer) {
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "utf-8") + "\"");
} else {
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + MimeUtility.encodeWord(filename) + "\"");
}
```

I tested it with firefox 3.6 , chrome 10.0 and Internet Explorer 8 and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

From [section 2.3 in the spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt), it seems you can't use non-US-ASCII characters:

> Current [[RFC 2045]](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) grammar restricts parameter values (and hence
>     Content-Disposition filenames) to US-ASCII.  We recognize the great
>     desirability of allowing arbitrary character sets in filenames, but
>     it is beyond the scope of this document to define the necessary
>     mechanisms.  We expect that the basic [[RFC 1521]](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1521.txt) `value'
>     specification will someday be amended to allow use of non-US-ASCII
>     characters, at which time the same mechanism should be used in the
>     Content-Disposition filename parameter.

Comment: This is accurate, but unhelpful.  :)

Comment: Gustafc, Thanks for your time and the RFC's which specified the reason for these undesired results.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's old question, it's still actual. I found solution that works for all my browsers.

See my post in other thread:
[Java servlet download filename special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325322/java-servlet-download-filename-special-characters/13359949#13359949)

In short, browsers expect that value in `filename` parameter is encoded in browsers native encoding (if no different charset is specified for `filename` parameter). Browser's native encoding is usually utf-8 (FF, Opera, Chrome), but for IE it is win-1250. Hence, if we put value into `filename` parametr, that is encoded by utf-8/win-1250 according to user's browser, it should work.

For example, if we have file named `omáčka.xml`,
for FireFox, Opera and Chrome I response this header (encoded in utf-8):

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="omĂˇÄŤka.xml"
```

and for IE I response this header (encoded in win-1250):

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="omáèka.jpg"
```

Java example is [in my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325322/java-servlet-download-filename-special-characters/13359949#13359949) that is mentioned above.

**Note #1 (@dkarp)**:

Be aware of using URLEncoder.encode() since this method doesn't encode input string into url-encoding. This method encodes input strings into form-encoding which is very similiar but differs in some cases - for example space character ' ' is encoded as '+' instead of '%20'.

To perform correct url encoding you should rather use URI class:

```
URI uri = new URI(null, null, "foo-ä-€.html", null);
System.out.println(uri.toASCIIString());
```